# Is it bad practice to use variable names as function names in conditions?

Tags: php

**Example:**

```
$var = 'post_type_archive';
$name = 'some-archive';
$condition = 'is_'.$var;
if($condition($name))
```

Is that considered a big fat no-no? If so, how else could one accomplish something similar?

Comment: I would want to see a fuller explanation of what you want before commenting on a better option.

Comment: Sometimes this is the best way of accomplish what you want, so no. It's not a big no-no.

Comment: Do you think you'll be able to understand that code in a year's time? Would another developer be able to understand what you have done? I think the answer is probably 'no', in which case you shouldn't do it. Needing to do something like this is an indication that your project architecture is poorly designed and needs to be revised.

Comment: @vascowhite That's what comments are for.

Comment: No, not really. Comments can't turn poor code into good code. See tip #12 here http://www.devtopics.com/13-tips-to-comment-your-code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a bad practice when you limit the usage to certain cases. One of these cases might be dynamically calling functions based on the given GET parameters.

But I would recommend to use [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/call-user-func) instead. It makes clear what you are going to do and the code is much more readable. Remember to always check the existence of the function with [`is_callable()`](http://php.net/is-callable).

`call_user_func()` will not work with built-in functions though.

Comment: And if you're basing it on `$_GET`, at however great a remove, **always** make sure you've whitelisted the possible functions that can be called in some way!

Comment: A special prefix in the function name prevents abuses. E.g.: `call_user_func('get_parameter_function_'. $_GET['func'])`

Comment: Or, even better, stick them in a namespace or class, so it's obvious where to find the full list, too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to do this. Just make sure you only do it when you actually need it, because as the commenter said, it can easily be a readability issue. If the list of possible functions to be called is short, consider using a switch statement instead.

Comment: The list of possibilities is pretty large.

Comment: Which implies that you have a large set of functions called `is_x` for different `x`. Perhaps these themselves should be replaced with one function containing a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do that, you need to be sure the dynamically created function name is always valid, or you will get a fatal error at runtime. At the very least, you should use `is_callable()` to check that the function exists.